# re.findall seems to have side effects

Tags: python, regex

I'm rather new to python. Interested in the imaging library (pillow). I wrote a program that collects data from images then writes it to a file. When retrieving the data from the file I use regular expressions (`re.findall()`) to find, and separate the data, then a print statement, to see the data in the terminal (Linux).

The part that creates and writes to the file is;

```
fout = open('pic_data', 'a')
fout.write(' '.join(map(str, FN1)))
fout.write('\n')    
fout.write(' '.join(map(str, X1)))
fout.write('\n')    
fout.close()
```

The data file contains:

```
/img-col/new-one/pic1_picture-file_1280.jpg
19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81
/img-col/new-one/pic2_picture-file_500.jpg
108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27
/img-col/new-one/pic3_picture-file_500.jpg
169 126 91 37 24 18 170 115 74 158 117 87 196 130 96 201 136 104 207 135 110 200 136 101 160 110 61 188 121 92 196 174 153 176 158 144
/img-col/new-one/pic4_picture-file_500.jpg
108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27
/img-col/new-one/pic5_picture-file_1280.jpg
19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81
```

The code that opens the file and prints it to the terminal is:

```
import re
from numpy import *
file = open('pic_data', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():    
    line = line.strip('\n')    
    #print line, type(line)
    a1 = re.findall('^\/.*\.jpg', line, flags=0)
    print a1, 'number 1 - a1'
    a2 = re.findall('^\d.*\d$', line, flags=0)  
    print a2, 'number 2 - a2'
    x = array(a2)
    print x, 'number 3 - x'
```

This is where the misbehavior happens, when printing to the terminal there are empty holes in the data. This is what the output looks like:

```
grumpy@grumpy-desktop ~ $ python /home/grumpy/z-working-stuff/py-2.py
['/img-col/new-one/pic1_picture-file_1280.jpg'] number 1 - a1
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
['19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81'] number 2 - a2
[ '19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81'] number 3 - x
['/img-col/new-one//img-col/new-one/pic2_picture-file_500.jpg'] number 1 - a1
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
['108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27'] number 2 - a2
[ '108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27'] number 3 - x
['/img-col/new-one//img-col/new-one/pic3_picture-file_500.jpg'] number 1 - a1
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
['169 126 91 37 24 18 170 115 74 158 117 87 196 130 96 201 136 104 207 135 110 200 136 101 160 110 61 188 121 92 196 174 153 176 158 144'] number 2 - a2
[ '169 126 91 37 24 18 170 115 74 158 117 87 196 130 96 201 136 104 207 135 110 200 136 101 160 110 61 188 121 92 196 174 153 176 158 144'] number 3 - x
['/img-col/new-one//img-col/new-one/pic4_picture-file_500.jpg'] number 1 - a1
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
['108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27'] number 2 - a2
[ '108 74 64 51 40 38 152 116 102 155 121 109 165 133 120 198 171 160 255 255 253 119 85 73 26 28 23 26 26 24 90 67 61 28 30 27'] number 3 - x
['/img-col/new-one//img-col/new-one/pic5_picture-file_1280.jpg'] number 1 - a1
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
['19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81'] number 2 - a2
[ '19 16 7 197 161 127 38 28 18 180 119 90 202 124 102 215 151 116 255 235 208 252 216 192 244 208 174 84 36 26 193 158 126 170 118 81'] number 3 - x
grumpy@grumpy-desktop ~ $
```

Technically all the data is present, but with holes - the empty square brackets, these should not be empty.

```
[] number 2 - a2
[] number 3 - x
[] number 1 - a1
```

The 'number # - X' is for debugging, let me know what should be there, etc.

The problem is I am running a coef (coef = corrcoef(x,y)) on the data and the module chocks on empty data sets. Where are these empty matches coming from, and how can I avoid or ignore them?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have two regular expressions, and if I'm reading them properly they're mutually exclusive - if one matches, the other won't. The ones that don't match return the empty list.

Comment: You have to understand that you are doing a re.findall() operation on each line you are reading from the file in a loop.
So for example when you are in your first iteration of `for line in file.readlines():` you match the ".jpg" regex and get an iterator for it but all the other matches fail giving you a empty list.